# Ubuntu focal on WSL2 unable to download files

Tags: networking, dns, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running Ubuntu focal as a WSL2 installation on Windows 10.

It appears that my Ubuntu installation is unable to download any files. I have illustrated it with a simple `wget` command, but the situation is blocking `sudo apt update` and any other system updates.

`ping` is returning expected results.

The host Windows system is working as expected, and is able to display the file that `wget` couldn't fetch. This can be seen in the image below

[image: Windows browser works]

Here is a sample session:

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
$ uname -r
5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WesPeacock/SampleSFM/master/README.md
--2021-10-02 20:30:05--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WesPeacock/SampleSFM/master/README.md
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 185.199.111.133, 185.199.110.133, 185.199.109.133, ...
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|185.199.111.133|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|185.199.110.133|:443... ^C
$ ping raw.githubusercontent.com
PING raw.githubusercontent.com (185.199.111.133) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from cdn-185-199-111-133.github.com (185.199.111.133): icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=21.0 ms
64 bytes from cdn-185-199-111-133.github.com (185.199.111.133): icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=22.8 ms
64 bytes from cdn-185-199-111-133.github.com (185.199.111.133): icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=22.2 ms
64 bytes from cdn-185-199-111-133.github.com (185.199.111.133): icmp_seq=4 ttl=59 time=22.1 ms
^C
--- raw.githubusercontent.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 21.047/22.023/22.798/0.627 ms
```

Comment: This sounds like a firewall configuration issue. Do you run any separate Windows anti-virus or firewall software? You might need to add allow exceptions for all executable files in your WSL installation.

Comment: @galexite was right.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was that the Windows anti-virus software firewall had set the local network as untrusted.